# Difference between compressionQuality and reducing the imagesize (height and width) in swift

Tags: swift, uiimage

In the following code i am uploadin images to server by reducing its compressionQuality and  also reducing the size(height and width of the image.But i want to know what is realy happening in the both of the cases. if i will only reduce the compressionQuality or only compress the height and width of the perticular what will happen ? Can any one please explain me this concept.

```
func compressImage() -> UIImage? {

    enum JPEGQuality: CGFloat {
        case lowest  = 0
        case low     = 0.25
        case medium  = 0.5
        case high    = 0.75
        case highest = 1
    }

    // Reducing file size to a 10th
    var actualHeight: CGFloat = self.size.height
    var actualWidth: CGFloat = self.size.width
    print("DEBUG: actualHeight \(actualHeight)")
    print("DEBUG: actualWidth \(actualWidth)")

    //For iphone 5s
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = 1136.0
    let maxWidth: CGFloat = 640.0


    var imgRatio: CGFloat = actualWidth/actualHeight
    let maxRatio: CGFloat = maxWidth/maxHeight
    var compressionQuality: CGFloat = JPEGQuality.highest.rawValue

    if actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth {
        compressionQuality = JPEGQuality.high.rawValue
        if imgRatio < maxRatio {
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth
            actualHeight = maxHeight

            print("DEBUG: actualHeight after compression  \(actualHeight)")
            print("DEBUG: actualWidth after compression \(actualWidth)")
        } else if imgRatio > maxRatio {
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
            print("DEBUG: actualHeight after compression  \(actualHeight)")
            print("DEBUG: actualWidth after compression \(actualWidth)")
        } else {
            actualHeight = maxHeight
            actualWidth = maxWidth
            compressionQuality = JPEGQuality.highest.rawValue
            print("DEBUG: actualHeight after compression  \(actualHeight)")
            print("DEBUG: actualWidth after compression \(actualWidth)")
        }
    }
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: actualWidth, height: actualHeight)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    self.draw(in: rect)
    guard let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    guard let imageData = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: compressionQuality) else {
        return nil
    }
    print("DEBUG: IMAGE DATA IS \(imageData)")

    return UIImage(data: imageData)
}
```

Comment: Less width/height (in pixels for instance) => Less pixels to encode. compressionQuality: lose some info during the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

To compress an image is to save the image in its current state such as size though at a lower quality. This results in an image being the same size in pixels though a smaller file size. The quality is lost with less pixel density "data" or with a reduction in colour.

In most cases you have a determined size you would like an image to be displayed. Especially for web design. If you would like to save on download time and file size you would op for compressing the image or compare saving the image as jpg vs png. Each of which use a different compression algorithm out of the box.

You could just make the image smaller in pixel size. But then you would be stretching your image to fit a larger size and it wouldn't look anywhere as crisp.

If you have a lot of large images and you know you would never use them at their true size, to save space you could make those images smaller.

Changing an image in any way will always have an effect on quality.

Answer (score 0):

UIImageview automatically scales and crops according to the behavior specified by its content mode property.

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.image = image
```

Then why do we need to resize that image? 
**When it's larger than the imageview that's displaying it.**
Lets say you have 30Mb image.To display that image on the imageview first need to decode the jpeg to bitmap. it will take lot of memory usage for fitting that on imageview and also app might be getting slow for the user.Thats why we use image resizing. there is a technique. Its called downsampling. So Image re sizing means you're going to shorten the resolution of the image. thus image size will be reduced.

Image compression is lowering the file size of the image without compromising the resolution. Of course lowering file size will affect the quality of the image.